# HDD's reallocated sector count is increasing slowly. Should I be concerned?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, smart

A month ago, my external hard drive reported 6 reallocated sectors, with CrystalDiskInfo advising "Caution". A week or two later, this increased to 7. Today, after a very long operation (encrypting the whole drive, then doing a new backup on it), it increased to 8.

The drive was bought about a year ago; it has gotten a few shocks, but always worked correctly, and the falls didn't happen at the same time as the sector reallocations.

Should I expect this drive to die soon? Does this counter typically keep increasing at the same rate, or warn of a larger failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you should worry. Replace the drive ASAP.

Every harddrive medium surface has some manufacturing defects - to compensate those, a number of additional sectors on the medium are originally unused, then when defects are found those defective sectors are retired and some of the spare setors are used.

On a healthy drive, this number should stay constant or rise very, very slowly (itoom 1 per year). If this number rises sharply, it means that part of the medium surface is in the process of failing, and when those spare sectors are used up the drive has failed.

If your drive is a Seagate, be especially concerned: Those have the property of typically failing rather fast, once the reallocated sector count grwos.